# Problemas con permisos, en archivos

Tags: wordpress, cms

Estoy desarrollando una página utilizando worpress, el problema es que no puedo permitir que otros usuarios tengan acceso a la carpeta `/wp-content/uploads/`, pero si modifico los permisos desde el el administrador de archivos del hosting, le quito permiso a 'otros' y no le doy ninguno, ahí si no pueden acceder desde la url a dicha carpeta, bien, el problema viene que la pagina no me carga las imágenes, ya que estan dentro de la carpeta uploads.

Alguien sabe alguna solucion a este error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, el error era sencillo, solo cambie los permisos de la carpeta a

> drwx--x--x (711)

y listo